# How to config a jQuery plugin using ajax_command_invoke? Drupal 7

Tags: jquery-plugins, drupal-7

I know [`ajax_command_invoke`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7) can invoke a jQuery method (like `attr()`, `addClass()`, etc.) with some optional arguments. But how can I use it to config a jQuery plugin, like `jCarouselLite`, `Cycle` and etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write the code you want to invoke and include it in a jQuery function first:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.myJavascriptFunction = function(data) {
      alert(data);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then, you can load it into the command array using ajax_command_invoke:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "myJavascriptFunction", array($myCustomParameters));

return array(
  '#type' => 'ajax',
  '#commands' => $commands,
);
```

This is basically the approach they discuss at http://drupal.org/node/1028410.

Answer (score 0):

See also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73738/17676 -- instead of writing new jQuery functions, you can also use events and triggers.

Comment: I didn't have time for trying this but seems like a good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

maybe this links be usefull for you :

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7
http://drupal.org/node/1028410
http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/includes!ajax.inc/DC

and this
http://phpcrossref.com/drupal/includes/ajax.inc.sum.html

some feature in drupal 7 not document obvious and just refer us to example module :(

Comment: Downvote for just providing links which anyone can find on Google.

Comment: Actually, Drupal problems/solutions are surprisingly hard to figure out, even with whatever spare + outdated "documentation" one finds on Google!  Often, what's obvious for one person is totally unknown and hidden "documentation" in the form of "commentary" on some random drupal.org/node/xyz page.